# IEnumerable<T> as a DataSource for a data driven test

Tags: .net, datasource, ienumerable, mstest, data-driven-tests

Is it possible in .Net to create a data driven test that uses an `IEnumerable<T>` as a `DataSource`?

The problem is:
There is a class that I want to test. Its behavior slightly differs, depending on an `int` value that it receives as a constructor parameter.
And there is a static method that returns `IEnumerable<int>` of all possible values for that constructor parameter.

Comment: What test framework? NUnit?

Comment: Have you met Moq? https://github.com/Moq/moq4

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker The default one from Microsoft.

Comment: @Santhos can it help in such situation?

Comment: It was a tip. I cannot be sure, you haven't given us much information. Can you maybe show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution. Not really satisfied with it, but it works.

```
[DataSourceGenerator("source.csv")]
public class DataDrivenTests
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "source.csv", "source#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    //The source is generated automatically by DataSourceGenerator attribute
    public void DataDrivenTest()
    {
        //Here you can implement a data driven test of your own
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
internal sealed class DataSourceGeneratorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DataSourceGeneratorAttribute(string fileName)
    {
        var csvContent = GenerateCsvContent();

        File.WriteAllText(fileName, csvContent);
    }
    private string GenerateCsvContent()
    {
        //Here you can generate content for your csv
    }
}
```